Whenever i tried to open new project, it get connected to main server for gradle, how can i avoid it by installing all the gradles locally
Whenever i  opened a new project in android studio, it connects to main server automatically for gradle build and update.  I want to reduce that time by having all the gradles locally,  how to achieve this
i tried installing all the gradles locally and pointing the gradle location to that file, but not working
